# border margin-bottom not working CSS

Tags: html, css, border, margin

I have a border which I am wrapping around the page using `<div>`. The parent element is the actual page. I can't seem to figure out why the `margin-bottom` is not working.

```css
.page_border {
  border: 20px solid;
  height: 960px;
  width: 720px;
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: -24px;
  margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_border"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the fact you have the bottom margin set to a negative value might be the issue if what you want to do is put a margin between the div and the bottom of the page. If you remove the negative sign that should work. See below.

```css
.page_border {
  border: 20px solid;
  height: 960px;
  width: 720px;
  margin: 24px 0 24px 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page_border"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I did not try that. I was under the impression that by making the bottom margin negative it would move it higher.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on what you are asking completly.

Could you not put a height value onto the body tag, and then adjusting the `height: value;` from div, by doing so though the body will have a fixed height and you may need to set `overflow: auto;` on the div.

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is that margin-bottom is not working because it does not place a margin between the bottom of the border and the bottom of the page. I tried removing the height, but this closes the vertical opening of the border completely. I can't seem to figure out why margin-bottom is not working.

Comment: Sorry i meant, Put a height value onto the body tag, then adjust the height of the div by minus 24px or whatever value you want, then set an overflow: auto; onto the div. this should work then